# Only allow html tags from WYSIWYG BBCode Editor

Tags: php, javascript, html, bbcode

I want the basic things such as bold, italic, underline, link, image, list and colors. I am using [bbcode editor](http://wysiwygbbcode.codeplex.com/). I am also using strip_tags in my php, I want to bypass this so it only allows the above and not things such as mysql queries, javascript tags, header tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked. strip_tags($post,'ALLOWED TAGS HERE');

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, i would probably do some  `str_replace` before `strip_tags` 
so any `<Tag`  As well as `</tag` becomes `[[{{Tag` or `[[{{/tag` (some characters that would not mistakenly be typed) and then replace them back after `strip_tags`

NOTE. only on the tags you wish to allow.

Comment: I guess my big mistake was the layout I did, I did stip tags before the if statements to replace and now it works like a dream. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to accept this answer, if it was what you were looking for :)